# How to create a subset of dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-processing

I have a large dataset(pandes dataframe) with following headers
`RAM = [f"RUT1_Azi_{i}" for i in range(10)]`
`RDP = [f"RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_{i}" for i in range(´10)]`
`RDI = [f"RUT1_Dtctn_ID_{i}" for i in range(10)]`
`REM = [f"RUT1_Elev_{i}" for i in range(10)]`
`RCC = ['RUT1_Cycle_Counter']`

Now i want to make many subset from the original dataframe as below.

**subset_0**
`index,RUT1_Cycle_Counter, RUT1_Azi_0, RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_0, RUT1_Dtctn_ID_0, RUT1_Elev_0`

**subset_1**
`index,RUT1_Cycle_Counter, RUT1_Azi_1, RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_1, RUT1_Dtctn_ID_1, RUT1_Elev_1`
.
.
.
**subset_9**
`index,RUT1_Cycle_Counter, RUT1_Azi_9, RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_9, RUT1_Dtctn_ID_9, RUT1_Elev_9`

How can I do this in python?
i am a beginner in python

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You need to take some `pandas` tutorials. There are many different ways to specify and calculate subsections of full dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```py
RAM = [f"RUT1_Azi_{i}" for i in range(10)]
RDP = [f"RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_{i}" for i in range(10)]
RDI = [f"RUT1_Dtctn_ID_{i}" for i in range(10)]
REM = [f"RUT1_Elev_{i}" for i in range(10)]

# made up example with the columns above
cols = RAM + RDP + RDI + REM
nrows = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(nrows * len(cols)).reshape(nrows, -1), columns=cols)
```

Now:

```py
subsets = [df[list(subcols)] for subcols in zip(RAM, RDP, RDI, REM)]
```

For example:

```py
>>> subsets[5]
   RUT1_Azi_5  RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_5  RUT1_Dtctn_ID_5  RUT1_Elev_5
0           5                  15               25           35
1          45                  55               65           75
2          85                  95              105          115
3         125                 135              145          155
4         165                 175              185          195
5         205                 215              225          235
6         245                 255              265          275
7         285                 295              305          315
8         325                 335              345          355
9         365                 375              385          395
```

**Edit**: modified answer to include a common list of columns for all subsets (`RCC = ['RUT1_Cycle_Counter']`):

```py
subsets = [df[RCC + list(subcols)] for subcols in zip(RAM, RDP, RDI, REM)]
```

Comment: >>>    print(subsets[5]) gives  
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you really had the definition as indicated `RAM = [f"RUT1_Azi_{i}" for i in range(10)]` etc., and all those columns exist in your `df`, then `subsets` should be of length 10.

Comment: ok,i understood.i have other header like 'Cycle_counter' which occur only once in original dataframe,I want to include this header in every subset.How can i do this?i tried this` **subsets = [df[list(subcols)] for subcols in zip('RUT1_Cycle_Counter',RAM,RDM,RCM,RVM,REM)]`** and didn't worked.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: ` subsets = [df[list(RCC + subcols)] for subcols in zip(RAM, RDP, RDI, REM)]`  
**TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list**

Comment: oops: fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can natively call a subset of a dataframe
as long as `list_of_subset_headers` is a subset of your dataframes columns just write

```
sub_df=df[list_of_subset_headers]
```

Or in this case :

```
sub_df0=df[['RUT1_Azi_0', 'RUT1_Dtctn_Probb_0', 'RUT1_Dtctn_ID_0', 'RUT1_Elev_0']]
```

Comment: how to do this for morethan 10 subsets?